# Graphing 3D matrix in Python - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I feel like I must be missing something extremely simple. I'm trying to graph a 3D matrix in a scatterplot. This is what I have

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D as axes
from matplotlib import cm

mat = np.matrix([ [245, 10, 3], [245, 7, 3], [246, 10, 3] ])
matt = mat.T

x = matt[0]
y = matt[1]
z = matt[2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', c = 'red')

plt.show()
```

Simple, right? But I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 248, in draw
    for col in self.collections]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 319, in do_3d_projection
    vxs, vys, vzs, vis = proj3d.proj_transform_clip(xs, ys, zs, renderer.M)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 203, in proj_transform_clip
    return proj_transform_vec_clip(vec, M)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 160, in proj_transform_vec_clip
    vecw = np.dot(M, vec)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

which I'm not sure how to fix. Where am I going wrong? The code is pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414619/creating-a-3d-plot-from-a-3d-numpy-array), so maybe I'm cutting the matrix wrong or something? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841827/3d-plotting-with-python) doesn't address the problem either. Any ideas?

*Edit*: Okay, I ended up just re-slicing it the old fashioned way via：

```
sx, sy = mat.shape

for i in range(0, sx):
    x.append(mat[i,0])
    y.append(mat[i,1])
    z.append(mat[i,2])
```

Which is probably not the best way but I got annoyed. And it works, so there's that.

Comment: You should put the complete traceback, not just a small part of it.

Comment: Edited in. Is it a problem with my version of python/matplot lib?

Comment: If you solved the problem, please put it as an *answer*, not as an addition to the question. And then mark it as solved (you can answer and mark your own answers). That way, it's easy to the problem has a solution.

Comment: I think that if you replace `np.matrix` by `np.array`, you may get what you want. Matrices behave differently than (2-D) arrays in numpy, and the slicing you're liking for won't work this way.

Comment: Well, I would prefer to find a method for slicing it DIRECTLY instead of having to do what I suspect is not the Python Approved Answer (TM). That's why I didn't put it as an answer. I will change it later if nothing else pops up, though.

Comment: And also, your solution turned out to be what I need, so thanks! Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.